# Удалить класс у элемента при добавлении класса другому элементу на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Имеется меню с двумя вкладками которые содержат вложенные менюшки. При клике на вкладку должны происходить два события:

1) при клике на элемент, этому элементу добавляется класс `.active`, а у другого элемента класс `.active` должен удалиться.

2) у активной вкладки меню видимое. Второе меню скрыто, имеет класс `.hide`. И соответственно при клике на соответствующую вкладку меню становится видимым.

Как удалить класс `.active` у элемента при добавлении класса `.active` другому элементу? И как связать активные вкладки с отображением скрытого меню, т.е. удалить класс `.hide`?

[Код JS:](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/2xqgn8vq/)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var wrapnavs = document.getElementById('js-navigation'),
    navs = wrapnavs.getElementsByTagName('div');
for( var i = 0; i < navs.length; i++ ){
    navs[i].addEventListener('click', selectMenu);
}

function selectMenu() {
    if(this.classList.contains('active')){
        this.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
        this.classList.add('active');
    }
}

console.log('get to the choppa!!!');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделала так:

```
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var navs = document.querySelectorAll('#js-navigation div');
for( var i = 0; i < navs.length; i++ ){
    navs[i].addEventListener('click', selectMenu(i), false);
}

function selectMenu(iterator) {
    return function() {
        var parents = document.querySelectorAll('#js-navigation div');
        parents.forEach(function(item, iter) {
            item.classList.remove('active');

            if(iterator == iter) {
                item.classList.add('active');
            }
        });

        var topMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.ntk-top-menu');

        topMenu.forEach(function(item, iter) {
            item.classList.add('hide');
           if(iterator == iter) {
               item.classList.remove('hide');
           }
        });
    }
}
 });
```

**UPD**

Обновила код.

Comment: а разве может быть случай когда несколько элементов с классом active?